# Getting unique validation error from cypress version 5.5.0,what ever the number we input the field validation saying number already exists

Tags: cypress

Getting unique validation error from cypress version 5.5.0, what ever the number we input the field validation saying number already exists, however no issues before cypress version 5.4.0, can anyone please help how to resolve the issue?

[image: Screenshot with the error message]

Comment: It seems that this error is coming from your Web Application, rather than from cypress.

Comment: Hi @venkat, please provide some code with your question. Most likely this is not depending on the cypress version, as Alapan Das said, but if you provide more information, people would more likely to be able to help you.